# PC still booting on GNU GRUB even after boot-repair

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have an issue on my Asus. After I runned boot-repair on USB live, after rebooting the same message of Grub GNU 2.0 appears "minimal bash like-line editing is supported..."

I don't know what to do,

Here is the link http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/D9JQcvy33S/

The message says "Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file!", but I don't know how to do that.

Thank you,

Comment: Did you use Rufus program to burn the distro image onto your USB stick? If so, it's probably the reason why. I fixed it on my laptop by just copying contents of the distro image to my USB stick and used diskpart (Windows) to mark it as active (bootable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am very beginner  but yes I used Rufus for the USB live. But I have no Windows, and I only have accesse to Ubuntu USB LIVE with my USB bootable.

Comment: Your Boot-Repair report shows you booted live installer in UEFI mode. And you have Ubuntu on drive sdc (now) but it originally was sda. You show no sda, Ubuntu live installer is sdb, and actual hard drive with Ubuntu is sdc. Did you change SATA port order of drives on motherboard. If you unplug flash drive and turn UEFI Secure boot off (leave UEFI on, do not use BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode), do you get grub menu? Does it then boot or can you boot recovery mode? Or can you boot UEFI OS entry?

Comment: @oldfred I changed boot option priorities and now it shows
drive.google.com/open?id=1c0KySvuZ-iqA0Ra63ZZVR8-aVKV1fksl and drive.google.com/open?id=16BOXh39PuJv_vzHZhmLs4H6Cg1rYqU1r here is advanced page for Sata drive.google.com/open?id=1mVaaF6Uz34-wES2hycQB96KmQ8R51K-F and I turned off secure boot as per here drive.google.com/open?id=1yZqVvQ2SQu1BuMP9oaXurYPPwiDCT93R but I still get grub menu. "leaving UEFI on" (is there an option for that or does it mean to not turn pc off?), also I am writing this post from a live USB session.

Answer (score 1):

Your UEFI update created /EFI/grub not updating /EFI/ubuntu.
You can move /EFI/grub/grub.cfg to /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg and boot grub UEFI entry. Ubuntu UEFI grub boot expects to use & find grub.cfg in /EFI/ubuntu.
The ubuntu entry has an old GUID, so will not work.

Are you at this:
grub>

If so manually boot with:

```
set root=(hd2,gpt2)
configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Note that in report install was in sdc (hd2), but if you unplug flash drive it will be hd1, and when originally installed it was sda or in grub hd0, so you may have to experiment on which actually works. then see if the reinstall of grub works.

```
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64
sudo update-grub
```

See also:
[Grub loads instead of Ubuntu whenever my HP streambook reboots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054032/grub-loads-instead-of-ubuntu-whenever-my-hp-streambook-reboots?noredirect=1#comment1723215_1054032)

Comment: Thank you @Oldfred for your precious help,

Disabling fast boot and secure boot in UEFI has solved the issue after I reinstalled distro. 


Have a nice day,