# Grub loads instead of Ubuntu whenever my HP streambook reboots

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I recently decided to install Ubuntu on an old HP streambook I had lying around. I ran into an issue where, instead of booting Ubuntu, it would stay in grub. I don't have much experience with linux, but I was able to get Ubuntu to boot up by using the directions provided in [the answer to this posted question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159846/tried-to-boot-ubuntu-but-the-grub-rescue-prompt-shows-up-instead), but I find that, whenever my system reboots, it goes back to booting into grub. How do I get it to boot into Ubuntu automatically?

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info   If UEFI it may need a work around.

Comment: @oldfred I want to say it's UEFI. Here's the BootInfo Summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jBWbcYDB45/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is UEFI and you show grub not UEFI.
See these bug reports, they seem to have rolled out a version of grub efi boot that uses /EFI/grub (used by Debian) not standard Ubuntu /EFI/ubuntu:
Ubuntu 18.04 similar error /EFI/grub

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1781042

Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic installed /EFI/grub

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1775743

Can you manually boot?
Your install is in /dev/mmcblk0p2  so in grub that is gpt2.

```
grub> set root=(hd0,gpt2)
grub> configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Then once booted run these:

```
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: You can accept answer so others know a solution that works.