# GRUB2 error screen after multiple install attempts

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, lubuntu

My Asus laptop has a 32GB eMMC with Windows 10 preinstalled. I wish to replace it with Lubuntu for the system only has 2GB RAM, and a dual core 2.1GHz CPU.

Install to the eMMC failed twice, so I bought an 80GB HDD, mounted it in the PC's expansion bay, and installed Lubuntu there. However, installing alongside Windows sends me to a GRUB2 error message, as does partitioning manually, which I tried twice.

I can't solve it by searching the partitions for the boot directory, for `ls` in the GRUB menu only lists the filesystem type.

[image]

Comment: Please take pictures of the GRUB2 error screen, as well as the result of  `ls`, then click on https://askubuntu.com/posts/1054300/edit and add the result to your original post.

Comment: I tried but the website said that I should have more than 10 reputation to be able to post a picture

Comment: https://pastebin.com and other similar sites https://alternativeto.net/software/pastebin/ allow you to upload pictures; they will assign a URL address you can add to the original question so you can make the pictures available without having to wait for reputation to arrive.

Comment: See this similar issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054032/grub-loads-instead-of-ubuntu-whenever-my-hp-streambook-reboots

Comment: To see the files, use `ls (hd0,1)/` etc, i.e. put a `/` at the end.

Comment: Thank you I was able to boot into the system and I installed the grub again as said . But when I restarted the system I got the same problem again.

Comment: I mean from the solution that  " oldfred "  gave the link to . So is there a way to get the system to do it by it self every time ?