# PC still booting to GNU GRUB even after boot-repair (DELL G7)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I have an issue on my Dell G7 7588. After I runned boot-repair on USB live, after rebooting the same message of Grub GNU 2.0 appears "minimal bash like-line editing is supported..."

I've been following instruction here to boot ubuntu from my sabrent sata enclosure:
[Creating a PC-Boot-able Ubuntu Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332371/creating-a-pc-boot-able-ubuntu-installation/1332619#1332619)

Here is the link after running boot-repair:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7FZgdwX7JW/

The message says "Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda3/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file, which I have already adjusted on my BIOS.

Have been stuck on this problem for 3 days already. Its my first time using ubuntu and I am keen to get some work done on it. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You say you did it already but the `efibootmgr` shows otherwise, i.e., that it still boot from a non-working entry when it should be booting from "Ubuntu".

Comment: Is there anyway I can rectify this? I have already selected the efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file in my BIOS, but still seeing Grub.

Comment: You have UEFI, not BIOS, but apart from this small yet relevant semantics detail, again, you should choose the "Ubuntu" entry, not a specific "file".

Comment: Your UEFI boot entry is using the GUID of a NTFS partition, not an ESP. It looks like you reinstalled grub in BIOS mode. Use Boot-Repair from Ubuntu live installer booted in UEFI mode to make UEFI repairs. And then do a total reinstall of grub using its Advanced mode to choose install & drive. You do have ESP on both drives, so can choose either one. You may need to houseclean old incorrect UEFI boot entries, but new install  will overwrite at least one with new correct entry. https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader/497720#497720

Comment: Thank you all for your help and suggestions, I managed to find a solution thanks to all the input I have been giving. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution after tinkering around GRUB. Thanks @ChanganAuto for indicating to me the issue. But basically you have list the files on the Grub terminal:

```
Grub> ls
```

It should list all your mounted drives. Find the directory that contains your linux folder for example:

```
Grub> ls (hd0,gpt3)/
```

Once you find the folder that contains the linux installation, which should have: home/ boot/ lost+found etc. Set that folder as root folder following instructions from this post: [Grub loads instead of Ubuntu whenever my HP streambook reboots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054032/grub-loads-instead-of-ubuntu-whenever-my-hp-streambook-reboots?noredirect=1#comment1723215_1054032)

The commands are as follows:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,gpt3) #this is the folder with all the files I was talking about.
grub> configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

You will see that GRUB eventually boots to ubuntu. Open terminal and enter this:

```
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64
sudo update-grub
```

Problem solved, and you can finally start using ubuntu. Hope this helps anyone so they don't get stuck like I did.