# PC booting on "The environment block is too small"

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have an issue with my Asus X555L. When I boot a message appears "The environment block is too small, press any key to continue"

But when I press, there is a black screen and nothing happens. I have to shut down the PC.

This is a followup to this issue [PC still booting on GNU GRUB even after boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054006/pc-still-booting-on-gnu-grub-even-after-boot-repair)

And here is the boot-repair repot http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/scgxHJPzQb/

I really don't know what to do in this case.